# Haskell: printing intermediate values in ST monad

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn  how to use the `ST Monad`. I wonder if it is possible to print values as actions are taken. For example with a `Fibonacci` function in the `ST Monad`:

```
fibST :: Integer -> Integer
fibST n
  | n < 2     = n
  | otherwise =
    runST $ do
      a <- newSTRef 0
      b <- newSTRef 1
      go n a b
    where
      go 0 a _ = readSTRef a
      go n a b = do
        a' <- readSTRef a
        b' <- readSTRef b
        writeSTRef a b'
        writeSTRef b (a' + b')
        -- print "SOME INFORMATION HERE" <---
        go (n - 1) a b
```

What would I have to do in this case?

@Vikstapolis suggested to use `IORef` instead

```
fibIO :: Integer -> IO Integer
fibIO n
  | n < 2     = pure n
  | otherwise =
    do
      a <- newIORef 0
      b <- newIORef 1
      go n a b
    where
      go 0 a _ = readIORef a
      go n a b = do
        a' <- readIORef a
        b' <- readIORef b
        writeIORef a b'
        writeIORef b (a' + b')
        print a' -- intermediate values
        go (n - 1) a b
```

Comment: If for debugging, use `trace`. If not for debugging, it shouldn't be `ST`

Comment: The type `Integer -> Integer` promises that no I/O will occur. GHC enforces that by preventing prints. If it's for debugging purposes only, `trace` provides an exception top that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*TLDR:* No, you cannot use `print` or other IO-related functions in the ST monad. Use `IORef`s in the IO monad for both mutability and the ability to print values.

*Full answer:*
In Haskell, every value is immutable. This helps preserve its purity. Purity also does not allow side effects such as printing or user input.
A program which cannot take input or print output, however, is useless. So, Haskell has *explicit impure functions* within the `IO` monad. By means of [`IORef`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html), you can also have mutability within the IO monad.

But sometimes, you need to use mutability to increase the efficiency of a function, and can guarantee that the function is pure or *referentially transparent* (i. e. The same input will always give the same output). This is the purpose of the `ST` monad.

The `ST` monad doesn’t allow arbitrary side effects such as printing, since that would destroy its purity. It only allows interior mutation within it, and once you escape the monad using `runST`, it appears as a pure computation to the rest of the program.

So, if you really need to print values and have mutation, use `IORefs` in the `IO` monad. For pure functions with interior mutation, use `ST`.

Note: it is possible to add IO to pure functions with [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO), and to ST with [`unsafeIOToST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Lazy-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeIOToST). As the name indicates, they are unsafe and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary (which they usually aren’t).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Do you have the time to write out an example?

Comment: see my attempt in the edit

Comment: @matt Your edit looks good, I don't have time to try it out right now but there's really only a couple of changes when converting from `ST` to `IO`: `readSTRef` and `writeSTRef` become `readIORef` and `writeIORef`, and you can't escape the monad using any equivalent to `runST` so the function needs to return an `IO something`.